# How can I pass object in a querystring to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, query-string

I have a JavaScript that sends an error message to a controller in Json response:

```
window.location.href = "/Error/Index?errorMessage=" + data.responseJSON.Message;
```

Json response also has a stack trace. I want to pass it as well to a controller, but I do not want to do it by sending two parameters in a querystring. I want to create an object containing error message and stack trace properties and send it in a query string. Something like that:

```
    var obj = ({
        ErrorMessage: data.responseJSON.Message,
        StackTrace:   data.responseJSON.StackTrace
    });

window.location.href = "/Error/Index?obj=" + obj
```

How can I declare `Index()` method in the controller and how would I retrieve the properties on the `View`?

Comment: You have no choice but to use `"/Error/Index?errorMessage=xxx&StackTrace=yyy"` if you are making a GET (your method can always contain a parameter for a model containing those 2 properties)

Comment: why not use AJAX?, and serialise the data from the form?